# How to create a load test with unique ip addresses

Tags: ip, load, performance-testing

I am looking to run a load test and send some traffic to a website. The problem that I am having is that I would like for all of this traffic to have unique IP addresses. So that if I send 100 requests, I would like for those requests to come from 100 IPs.

Are there any tools to help me accomplish this? Something like JMeter runs from your host, so that would not work. But is there something else like this that can send a load from many unique hosts? Or maybe some kind of proxy tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough machines you can consider [JMeter Distributed Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf), JMeter can be executed in "clustered" mode when one master machine orchestrates a number of slaves.

If you have only one machine where you can launch JMeter and you still need to send requests from multiple IP addresses - it still can be done. Take a look at "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) sampler - there is `Source Address` input where you can provide the source IP address for the request.

[image: HTTP Request Source Address]

Given you have enough IP addresses or [IP aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing) you should be able to accomplish your testing using only one machine. Check out [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter) article for detailed information, configuration instructions and demo.